# Django - Accessing model from django.contrib's User class via ManyToManyKey

Tags: django, django-views

I am making a Hacker News Clone in Django as taught in a Tuts+ Course [[**Git Repo**](https://github.com/croach/tutsplus-django)]

In [**views.py**](https://raw.github.com/croach/tutsplus-django/master/stories/views.py) file, for vote view, I tried using this code to increase security by checking if user has liked the story already.

```
@login_required
def vote(request):
    story = get_object_or_404(Story, pk=request.POST.get('story'))
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated() and story not in user.liked_stories:
        story.points += 1
        story.save()
        user.liked_stories.add(story)
        user.save()
    return HttpResponse()
```

But it gives me this Error:

```
NameError: global name 'liked_stories' is not defined
[18/Aug/2013 19:26:43] "POST /vote/ HTTP/1.1" 500 11148
```

I am able to use `user.liked_stories` in `index` view so why not in `vote` view?

Error:

```
Internal Server Error: /vote/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sourabh/.virtualenvs/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/sourabh/.virtualenvs/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 25, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sourabh/Code/django_apps/HackerNews/stories/views.py", line 53, in vote
    if user.is_authenticated() and story not in liked_stories:
NameError: global name 'liked_stories' is not defined
[18/Aug/2013 20:08:35] "POST /vote/ HTTP/1.1" 500 11161
```

Comment: the error says global name 'liked_stories' not defined, seems like your script uses this undefined variable somewhere else? so which line of your code throws the error?

Comment: The code you have posted would not give this error. You must have referenced `liked_stories` on its own, without going through `user`, somewhere.

Comment: Its in `user.liked_stories` part. If I remove `and story not in user.liked_stories`, everything works fine. I added complete error.

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
if user.is_authenticated() and story not in liked_stories:
```

In this line the error is thrown. The code you have posted does not resemble the code you are executing.

Comment: I already knew that this part is causing the problem (see my comments above). Git Repo is of Tuts+ not mine, I tried to improve vote view but I can't access liked_stories, it says that its not defined.

Comment: All I can see is that your posted code is not the code you are executing, they differ...

Comment: The code [here](https://raw.github.com/croach/tutsplus-django/master/stories/views.py) does work and is different from the one I posted. I replaced `view(request)` in link with the code that I posted and it doesn't work, and gives error that I posted as well. I want to know how I can resolve the error.